# Is the part of defined password in a config.php file encrypted when used?

Tags: php, encryption

I am new with php in general and I read the following example of a configuration file to connect to a database.

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");
```

and I want to ask If the part of DB_PASSWORD variable is encrypted somehow, and if not Can I encrypt it ? 
How this file would be written in more professional way?

Comment: Nothing is encrypted in there and actually an encryption would not make any sense in there. It offers a false hope of security. Do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, the password is in clear text in the php file. Which is okay. Although you might not want to share it with whomever nor upload it on a public repo or similar with the actual passwords in it.

If you want an extra layer of abstraction, I would recommend using [Php dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) and use `.env` files (which are not shared and specific for each environment) to store all passwords and other environment specific data.

Comment: Some people say about not having this file in web root. So if I create a folder inside my domain.com and change folder permissions, I am not in web root correct?

Comment: Well, you would possibly like to place that type of files outside the /var/www (or other web folder) so its not accessible, but a sub-folder is still inside the folder :)